# Deserialize Json from array of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want my **final response from API** to look something like this:

```
{
    "someId" : [
        "12344",
        "fer33dw",
        "sdadadw23ed",
        "ljkljkj2"      
    ]
}
```

To do that I have created my `ResponseDTO` class to look like this:( which I might be wrong about)

```
public class ResponseDTO
{
    public List<string> someId { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Now imagine I have a `List<string>` of some values like this:

```
List<string> someValuesHere = new List<string>();
someValuesHere.Add("1234");  // etc....
```

So that `someValuesHere` is what I want to deserialzie and return as my response. So I did like this:

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseDTO>(someValuesHere);
```

But this doesn't even compile. Error says "Non Generic Method Cannot be used with Type Arguments"

I am sure it is something stupid I have done wrong but can't see it myself.

Comment: someValuesHere is not serialized so it cannot be deserialized, I think you want your result to be a result of 'Serialize' method.  The answer by Serge shows doing that.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use this code, it was tested and working properly

```
var someValuesHere = new ResponseDTO
{
 someId= new List<string>()
};
someValuesHere.someId.Add("1234"); 

string json= System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(someValuesHere);
someValuesHere = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseDTO>(json);
```

Comment: thanks but it gives a conversion error on this line string json= JsonSerializer.Serialize(someValuesHere);

Comment: @UnskilledCoder Add System.Text.Json name space

Comment: thanks now that error gone but the last line errors again, same error I had originally : Non Generic Method Cannot be used with Type Arguments